# ActionBarDrawerToggle не хочет дружить с CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, collapsing-toolbar-layout

При развернутом CollapsingToolbarLayout есть DrawerToggle, а когда его сворачиваю, ToolBar уходит вместе с ним (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ydnf.png). Как Сделать что бы ToolBar был всегда закреплен вверху?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        <ImageView
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:minHeight="100dp"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Java:

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
```

[image: ToolBar]

Comment: Попробуйте разные значения для атрибута: app:layout_scrollFlags

Answer (score 0):

```
    android:layout_height="200dp" - сделайте match_parent,
```

а вот в app_bar можно задать 200dp, до CollapsingToolbarLayout'a

```
   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
```